# Does "enum class" exist in C?

Tags: c, enums

For an assignment, I've been told to make a function that would take multiple parameters and return an "enum class" in C. However, all the documentation on the enum classes seems to be in C++, no matter how hard I Google. Can I use enum classes in C? And if so, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: This could be a terminology issue. C treats enums as a type. Try doing a web search for "C enum type", and you'll find some proper links. Here is an explanation of the difference between [enum type and class](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-5a-enum-classes/). I'm not sure if there is any C compiler would produce at least a warning for assigning one enum type to a variable of another enum type.

Answer (score -8):

Yes, C does include enums (although "enum class" is a misleading way to talk about them).

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/cpp/c-language/c-enumeration-declarations?view=vs-2017 :

They can be declared like so:

```
enum DAY            /* Defines an enumeration type    */
{
    saturday,       /* Names day and declares a       */
    sunday = 0,     /* variable named workday with    */
    monday,         /* that type                      */
    tuesday,
    wednesday,      /* wednesday is associated with 3 */
    thursday,
    friday
};
```

and  variables can be declared/defined like this:

```
enum DAY today = wednesday;
```

Comment: `enum class` is a C++ thing.

Comment: They are 2 different things. -1.